# Find representative who handles the most customers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I’m trying to list the representative that handles the most customers.

```
SELECT RTRIM(S.REP_FNAME) + ' ' + S.REP_LNAME AS [Representative], COUNT(C.REP_NUM) AS Customer(s) Per Rep]
FROM CUSTOMER C, SALESREP S 
WHERE S.REP_NUM = C.REP_NUM
GROUP BY RTRIM(S.REP_FNAME) + ' ' + S.REP_LNAME
```

My query returns:


 
Representative(s) Customer(s) Per Rep

Juan Perez            3

Richard Hull           4

Valerie Kaiser        4

Note* Richard and Valerie is what I want. It should be displayed as two records

Please let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: you mean only 1 rep who had the most customers?

Comment: i corrected my order by...  must be order `DESC`

Comment: What happens if there is a tie?

Comment: Your example has two that have the most customers (Richard and Valerie). How do you want to handle ties? Do you want only one record, or all of them in order from most to least? Your question is missing a few details; it's unclear what the result is that you're trying to obtain.

Comment: That is correct @BhupeshC

Comment: Richard and Valerie is what I want. It should be displayed as two records @KenWhite

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT RTRIM(S.REP_FNAME) + ' ' + S.REP_LNAME AS [Representative], COUNT(C.REP_NUM) AS [Customer(s) Per Rep]
 FROM CUSTOMER C
 JOIN SALESREP S 
   ON S.REP_NUM = C.REP_NUM
 GROUP BY RTRIM(S.REP_FNAME) + ' ' + S.REP_LNAME 
 HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNTS FROM (SELECT TOP(1) REP_NUM, COUNT(REP_NUM) AS COUNTS GROUP BY REP_NUM ORDER BY COUNT(REP_NUM) DESC ))
```

or you can use the name you gave it.:

`ORDER BY [Customer(s) Per Rep] DESC`

Or for a less sophisticated method:

```
SELECT TOP(1) RTRIM(S.REP_FNAME) + ' ' + S.REP_LNAME AS [Representative], COUNT(C.REP_NUM) AS [Customer(s) Per    Rep]
FROM CUSTOMER C, SALESREP S 
WHERE S.REP_NUM = C.REP_NUM
GROUP BY RTRIM(S.REP_FNAME) + ' ' + S.REP_LNAME 
ORDER BY [Customer(s) Per Rep] DESC
```

Comment: How is that different from what I just did. Its yielding the same results. Thx anyway!

Comment: i had to add `DESC` to `ORDER BY`, try it now.  You must set an ORDER BY

Comment: But I am looking for the REPS that handle the most customers which should not include Juan Perez 3

Comment: ok, will adjust.  your question is not clear, it looks like you want them in order of most sales, if you only want the max i will change answer.